# How to leave or completely mute a channel in Discord for desktop?

Tags: discord

I'm in several Discord channels, some potentially useful but full of irrelevant "@here" messages, and would like to get rid of their notifications in my task bar. I've already muted them and set their notification setting to "Nothing", yet still get the red message count icon on my task bar button even with the latest version of Discord. How to completely stop channel notifications, even by leaving the channel? Editing the channels is forbidden according to my mouse cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rightclick the server in question, notification settings, and change the `suppress @here and @everyone` setting. Also, above, change notification for @metion only.

Edit: Keep in mind, a discord admin can still send a mention using @here or @everyone. If you get notifications from members that have an admin role, you can only leave the channel in order to not get notified.

Comment: "Suppress @everyone and @here" is a [server setting](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360042792072/comments/360007262191), not per channel. I'll try "Mentions" for the annoying channels but doubt that works better than "Nothing".

Comment: The admins are spamming @here and there is no apparent way to leave the channels.

Comment: right click on the server, leave server. Or complain to the admins and ask them to stop

Comment: I'll try but they're senior colleagues at work. Already looking for a more mature company, though.